# Printing For loop values in text file - Batch Program

Tags: batch-file

I am using the below batch program to get the system drive details.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1" %%d in (
'wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=3 get deviceid ^| find ":"') do ( 
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('fsutil volume diskfree %%d') do (
    Call :ConvertBytes %%b GB Gigs
    Call :ConvertBytes %%b MB Megs
    echo %%d - %%a: !Gigs! GB (^!Megs! MB^)
    set s=%%d - %%a: !Gigs! GB (^!Megs! MB^)
    echo %s% >>C:\myfile.txt
    )
 )
pause;       
goto :eof
:ConvertBytes bytes unit ret
setlocal
if "%~2" EQU "KB" set val=/1024
if "%~2" EQU "MB" set val=/1024/1024
if "%~2" EQU "GB" set val=/1024/1024/1024
> %temp%\tmp.vbs echo wsh.echo FormatNumber(eval(%~1%val%),0)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 
'cscript //nologo %temp%\tmp.vbs' 
) do endlocal & set %~3=%%a
del %temp%\tmp.vbs
```

The output of this batch will be:

```
C: - Total # of bytes             : 98 GB (99,900 MB)
C: - Total # of avail free bytes  : 32 GB (33,122 MB)
D: - Total # of bytes             : 146 GB (150,000 MB)
D: - Total # of avail free bytes  : 138 GB (141,728 MB)
E: - Total # of bytes             : 222 GB (226,938 MB)
E: - Total # of avail free bytes  : 208 GB (213,473 MB)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here i am trying to write the output of the batch to a text file. for that i had given the `echo %s% >>C:\myfile.txt` statement inside the for loop. But its printing `ECHO is off.` in the text file.

I had tried giving the echo statement before pause; command, while doing like this only the last line (`E: - Total # of avail free bytes  : 208 GB (213,473 MB)`) of the output got write in the text file.

How to print all the 6 lines in the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this `echo %s% >>C:\myfile.txt`

with this

```
>>C:\myfile.txt echo !s!
```